# Using the Adobe browser plugin to view pdf files (or alternatives) on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: pdf, plugins, adobe-reader

I am in the process of applying for a Marie Curie fellowship, and the application forms are all online. Unfortunately, I need to fill out certain parts of the application by opening an editable pdf file using the Adobe browser plugin, and I have not been able to find any way to use this plugin on Ubuntu 14.04.

Is there any way to use this plugin (I don't really care which browser, as long as it works)? I don't think it will be even possible to use an alternative plugin with the same functions, since the application page very specifically tries to open that plugin.

There was also an option to do this off-line, but it required the pdf reader to be able to send back the information when one clicked a button in the document, and this did not work in Master pdf Editor (which is otherwise my goto program for pdf's with weird forms).

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thank you for the link, but as far as I can tell, this is not the same plugin. Or is the pdf capabilities part of Flash?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. (I removed the comment.)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson No worries (all searches also seem to end up pointing me to things about the Flash plugin rather than the one I really need).